# How do you associate a Model with a UIButton (or in general, UIViews) in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, properties

I have a screen that shows details of a "Newspaper" (model) instance. The ViewController of my screen has one property for this Newspaper model. A Newspaper instance contains several Article instances, and these Article instances must be represented as UIButtons in the screen. Tapping the UIButton must display an alert message containing the title of the Article.

What are some good ways to associate the UIButton with an Article model?
Basically, when tapping the UIButton, how do I retrieve the UIButton's corresponding Article instance?

I currently have two approaches in mind:

1. Override the UIButton, and add a property for the Article instance.

   - This violates the MVC model, since the view (UIButton) has a direct means of communication with the model (Article), but this will simplify button actions since the UIButton can simply call its property to know what Article instance will be used to do the action (display an alert message containing the title of the Article).
2. Create an NSArray of UIButtons (buttonsArray), and an NSArray of Article instances (articlesArray).

   - Index 0 of the buttonsArray correspond to index 0 of the articlesArray. The Article instance associated with the tapped UIButton will be based on the button's position in the array. In order to retrieve the corresponding Article of a UIButton, the buttonsArray must be looped until the tapped UIButton is found, and then getting the Article from the articlesArray using the same index.

Are there better ways to achieve this?

EDIT: The buttons will have animations and gesture recognizers.
Also, the information needed by the button action from the Article model does not only include the title (e.g. article position, or the object itself if it will be passed to another screen, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your 2nd approach, but use an NSDictionary instead of two arrays.

Or you could use your first approach but instead of adding a property for your article instance, just add a generic string property like 'additionalTitle' or sth. That way you don't create a direct dependency between your button class and your model class. You could then save the title for the alertview in this property.

Comment: I used NSDictionary instead of two arrays, so that I am assured that the associations are correct. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you anyway wanna use a `UITableView` with Cells where the UIButton is integrated?

Because if you would go with this approach you could use your second approach. Using an array storing all the articles and getting the tapped index of the table cell to load the article from the array. You could create a CustomCell containing a UIButton. The button doesn't even has to know which article lays under him. Its the tableview handling it with the clicked index.

If you don't want to use a `UITableView` *I would choose the second approach.*

Comment: The UIButtons will have animations (moving positions) based on gestures, and the different UIButtons can have different positions not relative to each other. Can the UIButtons still be represented using a Cell within a Table view given this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the approach generally used by Apple in iOS is more like a model - (view+controller) combined one. For example `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` are examples for view and controller joined together as a single entity. Considering this, storing a model value as part of `UIButton` subclass wont violate much about MVC as long it just acts as passing on the values between model and view. It may not be a perfect MVC, but that is something a developer has to decide whether to follow that way or not. Hence I would suggest the first approach since that looks pretty neat and ensure the readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton has a settable tag property which is an integer. The tag property can easily be matched up with an index into an array. So then on receiving a touch event you pull out the tag value and you know which article was tapped.